# Appending item from a list to a Pandas df with rules

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, while-loop

I'm creating a random meal generator. The idea is that it randomly selects meals from a dictionary and applies a day of the week in which to have that meal. It will just pick meals for a week so there will only be 7 recipes chosen. Here is my code so far:

```
meals = {'Recipe': ['Chicken Kebab', 'Chicken Balti', 'Chicken Stir Fry', 'Chicken Curry', 'Cola Chicken', 'Chicken Fajita Pie',
                    'Chicken in Black Bean Sauce', 'Stuffed Meatballs', 'Pesto Pasta'],
         'Book': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
         'Page': ['48', '50', '52', '58', '72', '74', '80', '87', '108'],
         'Category': ['Normal', 'Curry', 'Asian', 'Curry', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Asian', 'Pasta', 'Pasta'],
         'Vegetarian': ['No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes']}


df = pd.DataFrame(meals)

days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']

print (df)
mealdays = []
while len(meals['Recipe']) != len(days):
    days.append(" ")
while len(meals['Recipe']) != len(mealdays):
    day = random.choice(days)
    mealdays.append(day)
    days.remove(day)


random.shuffle(days)

df['Days'] = mealdays
print (df)
```

This works great for picking the meals at random, however what I want to do now is introduce some rules so that certain 'Category's aren't selected multiple times. For example, if a 'Curry' category recipe has been randomly selected for 'Mon', then I wouldn't want another 'Curry' Category recipe for the rest of the week. I'm assuming this would be an If statement within the second While loop, but I'm not sure what it would be.

Comment: Things would be much easier if `meals` were a list of dictionaries instead of a dictionary of lists.

Comment: But you only have 4 categories and there are 7 days.

Comment: When you pick a recipe, put its category into a list. Then when picking the next recipe, loop until you get a recipe that's not in the same category.

Comment: It's not about how many categories there are, there are more than 7 rows in the dataframe, I want the day of the week to be a new column that has a day of the week in it, the others will remain blank

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use `sample` to shuffle your df, then find and drop duplicates of curry and pasta:

```
cat = ["Curry", "Pasta"]

df = df.sample(frac=1)
s = df[df["Category"].isin(cat)].drop_duplicates("Category", keep="last").index
print (df[~df.index.isin(s)])

                        Recipe Book Page Category Vegetarian
6  Chicken in Black Bean Sauce    1   80    Asian         No
4                 Cola Chicken    1   72   Normal         No
2             Chicken Stir Fry    1   52    Asian         No
1                Chicken Balti    1   50    Curry         No
8                  Pesto Pasta    1  108    Pasta        Yes
0                Chicken Kebab    1   48   Normal         No
5           Chicken Fajita Pie    1   74   Normal         No
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your data so that you have at least 7 categories, otherwise it wouldn't be possible to add your constraint.  In any case, you could groupby the category and take 1 sample from each, then take a random sample of 7 of those, and map the days to them.

```
meals = {'Recipe': ['Chicken Kebab', 'Chicken Balti', 'Chicken Stir Fry', 'Chicken Curry', 'Cola Chicken', 'Chicken Fajita Pie',
                    'Chicken in Black Bean Sauce', 'Stuffed Meatballs', 'Pesto Pasta'],
         'Book': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
         'Page': ['48', '50', '52', '58', '72', '74', '80', '87', '108'],
         'Category': ['Normal', 'Curry', 'Asian', 'Curry', 'American', 'Diet', 'Asian', 'Pasta', 'Frozen'],
         'Vegetarian': ['No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes']}


df = pd.DataFrame(meals)

days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']


df.loc[df.groupby('Category').sample(1).sample(7).index, 'Days'] = days
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

Output

```
                      Recipe Book Page  Category Vegetarian Days
0                Chicken Kebab    1   48    Normal         No  Sun
1                Chicken Balti    1   50     Curry         No     
2             Chicken Stir Fry    1   52     Asian         No     
3                Chicken Curry    1   58     Curry         No  Fri
4                 Cola Chicken    1   72  American         No  Tue
5           Chicken Fajita Pie    1   74      Diet         No  Sat
6  Chicken in Black Bean Sauce    1   80     Asian         No  Wed
7            Stuffed Meatballs    1   87     Pasta         No  Mon
8                  Pesto Pasta    1  108    Frozen        Yes  Thu
```

Comment: I'm not looking for a different Category for each day of the week, there will just be certain categories which I wouldn't want to be selected twice, for example I wouldn't want 2 curry recipes in a week and I wouldn't want 2 pasta recipes in a week, the rest would be fine to be had multiple times in the week

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this. It works, as there are not that many days in a week. But [Henry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68367327/383793) looks much more efficient.

```py
certain_categories = ['Curry']

pool = df
picked = []
for day in days:
    meal = pool.sample(1)
    df.loc[meal.index, 'Days'] = day
    if meal['Category'].item() in certain_categories:
        picked.append(meal['Category'].item())
    pool = df[df['Days'].isnull() & ~df['Category'].isin(picked)]
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
    
print(df)
                        Recipe Book Page Category Vegetarian Days
0                Chicken Kebab    1   48   Normal         No     
1                Chicken Balti    1   50    Curry         No     
2             Chicken Stir Fry    1   52    Asian         No  Sun
3                Chicken Curry    1   58    Curry         No  Thu
4                 Cola Chicken    1   72   Normal         No  Tue
5           Chicken Fajita Pie    1   74   Normal         No  Fri
6  Chicken in Black Bean Sauce    1   80    Asian         No  Wed
7            Stuffed Meatballs    1   87    Pasta         No  Mon
8                  Pesto Pasta    1  108    Pasta        Yes  Sat
```